# Fencing of Redhat cluster 7 on VirtualBox

Tags: rhel, virtualbox, cluster

I am trying to create a 3 node Redhat Cluster 7 on Oracle VirtualBox VMs hosted on Windows Server 2012 R2.

What agent can I use for fencing? 
How do I go about it?

Note : I am creating a cluster for the first time, and this is a test setup just for learning.

Comment: Are you following a specific guide for setting up a cluster? Can you share the link? If you have the VirtualBox hypervisor setup to allow proper networking then it should not matter in the least what the host OS and hypervisor is...that being said, VirtualBox often falls short of delivering a serious virtualization environment for more than 1 or two systems with simple network requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is fence_vbox utility in [fence-agents](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/fence-agents) package, but for some reason(s) (licensing with VirtualBox, probably) this particular agent is not included in the RHEL/CentOS rpm repos. So I just ended up with building it from sources.

Answer (score 0):

**pacemaker**: It's responsible for all cluster-related activities, such as monitoring cluster membership, managing the services and resources, and fencing cluster members.

**corosync**: Is the framework used by Pacemaker for handling communication between the cluster nodes.

**pcs**: Provides a command-line interface to create, configure, and control every aspect of a Pacemaker/corosync cluster.

Comment: I understand. But I am asking about fencing agent to use in my case and how to use it?

Comment: Something like that https://www.thegeekdiary.com/setting-up-fencing-devices-in-a-pacemaker-cluster/?

Comment: Yes, But for VirtualBox hypervisor on windows.